# How do I resolve an embedded reference when an assembly is loaded?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

In a C# user control library project I have a reference to a DLL which instead of copying locally I include in the assembly as an embedded resource. I resolve this reference by attaching to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event in the constructor of the public control in my library and then loading the reference directly from the resource.

At runtime this works fine, but if I try to add my control library to the Visual Studio (2010) Toolbox I get an error about an unresolved reference. Presumably because none of my constructors are being called.

How can I resolve the embedded reference when the assembly is loaded?